# Select previous and next records in join statement

Tags: mysql

On the page for viewing posts I thought it would be a nice idea to have links for the next and previous posts. I thought I should get those 3 records in 1 query since I'm so smart and I had a bunch of time to waste anyway. So as you probably guessed I couldn't do it, but I'm interested to find the solution. Here is what I have

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.title,
       a.body,
       p.id    AS prev_id,
       p.title AS prev_title,
       n.id    AS next_id,
       n.title AS next_title
FROM   posts a
       LEFT JOIN posts p
              ON p.id < a.id
       LEFT JOIN posts n
              ON n.id > a.id
WHERE  a.id = ?
LIMIT  1
```

The problem is that for `prev_id` and `prev_title` I always get *the first* record in the table. I tried adding `ORDER BY` but it didn't really seem to affect the join. How can I select the previous and not the first record using a join like in the example?

Comment: can we assume that p.id is sequential and when you say next/previous is the next used Id?  so in Previous it would be the MAX ID before (<) P.Id and for N it would be the MIN (ID) after (>) P.ID? Or are you talking the next article in group which may have nothing to do with the IDs...  table structure sample data and/or a SQLFiddle would help; as the answer varies based on your table structure and data used.

Comment: @xQbert no it is pretty simple table and all but I don't want to hardcode `a.id - 1` and `a.id + 1` for prev and next because some posts may get deleted and gaps may occur

Comment: Although, 'next' and 'previous' are useful to 'us' as people. As far as SQL is concerned it really doesn't have the 'concept' of an 'ordered set (list)', That is is an 'output' of the process of processing your query. SQL queries 'know' about 'sets' which, sadly, are not 'ordered'.

Comment: @RyanVincent not quite sure I understand you, isn't one of the purposes of an auto increment unique primary key to help sort the set?

Comment: No! 'auto increment id's' are the 'magic' that the database uses to link related items together. You should never use them for anything other than finding out which things are 'linked to each other'. You must have some other information that is the 'user data key' on the record.

Comment: @RyanVincent well I don't mean to be rude but ordering by id makes pretty good sense to me, sorting the records in the order they were inserted, or opposite, no?

Comment: There is no 'one true way' of doing this stuff. If it works for you then that is fine by me. I just prefer 'another way'. Whatever works. I am keen to hear your opinions. 'Rude' or 'clearly stated', it needs to be said. I will listen. I don't take offence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that this one you might find helpful:

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.title,
       a.body,
       p.id    AS prev_id,
       p.title AS prev_title,
       n.id    AS next_id,
       n.title AS next_title
FROM   posts a
       INNER JOIN
       (
            SELECT 
                _a.id AS RefID,
                MIN(_a.id - _p.id) AS MinDistPrev,
                MIN(_n.id - _a.id) AS MinDistNext
            FROM   
                posts _a
                LEFT JOIN posts _p
                      ON _p.id < _a.id
                LEFT JOIN posts _n
                      ON _n.id > _a.id
            WHERE  
                _a.id = ?
            GROUP BY
                _a.id
       ) AS _PrevNextDist
        ON _PrevNextDist.RefID = a.ID
       LEFT JOIN posts p
              ON p.id < a.id
                 AND a.id - p.id = _PrevNextDist.MinDistPrev
       LEFT JOIN posts n
              ON n.id > a.id
                 AND n.id - a.id = _PrevNextDist.MinDistNext
LIMIT  1
```

**Additionally**, adding `ORDER BY p.id DESC` to the original code solved the problem as well

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.title,
       a.body,
       p.id    AS prev_id,
       p.title AS prev_title,
       n.id    AS next_id,
       n.title AS next_title
FROM   posts a
       LEFT JOIN posts p
              ON p.id < a.id
       LEFT JOIN posts n
              ON n.id > a.id
WHERE  a.id = ?
ORDER BY p.id DESC
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: Sorry I've just edited the answer - there was 2 mistakes - now should be OK.

Comment: whoaa! I still get an error. That seems waaay more complex than I expected. Don't you think I'd be better off running 2 more queries rather than having such logic in sql? Thanks for the effort!

Comment: No problem, the query should be OK just now, if you might test it again - a spelling mistakes in code. Sorry - was trying to write too fast :)

Comment: Yeah I saw that but if I hit "EXPLAIN" it turns out running 7 queries which I suppose is way too much for something as simple as that. It was interesting to find out the way to achieve that with the weird conditions I made up but I think I will just go ahead and use separate queries. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem but must say the task was very curious. Wish you all the best in New Year btw :)

Comment: Thanks, you too! I just found out that ordering by `p.id` descending solved the issue. My problem was that I was ordering by `a.id` wow. I'll just add this as additional solution to your answer, if you don't mind.

Comment: Of course np. Don't mind me- please mark as your solution the answer that really solved your problem.